# Flutter emulator ssh X11 forwarding issue

Tags: android, flutter, ssh, emulation, x11

I'm am trying to use flutter on a remote PC which I can access via ssh. I have set up X11 forwarding so that I can have GUI elements forwarded to me such as the flutter emulator.

After setting everything up, it seems that the flutter emulator will not appear correctly. The screen simply remains blank.

All other aspects of the emulator GUI work normally (e.g. the side bar and menu options). Additionally all other GUI applications appear to work just fine.

I've confirmed that, given physical access to the remote machine, the emulator functions correctly. It only has issues when forwarding over ssh. Have others experienced this? Is there some way I can debug this issue?

**Flutter emulator** (blank screen)
[image]

**Flutter Doctor**
[image]

Comment: Are you falling on one of those restrictions? https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-accel-restrictions

Comment: No, the remote machine isn't any kind of VM. It's a spare laptop which has hardware acceleration.

Running the emulator on that laptop directly (not over ssh) shows that the emulator runs correctly. The issue seems to come in to play _only_ when operating over ssh

Answer (score 0):

This shoudln't be related to flutter but the configuration of the avd you're trying to launch remotely.

I have been running into this issue sporatically myself, each fix seems different from the next so there's most likely multiple factors at play here. That said I think gpu acceleration is at the core of the issue, if the below doesn't work for you, try to investigate in that direction.

```
emulator -avd *emulator-name* -gpu host
```

Was able to resolve my problem. The value can be set permanently in your avd config.ini file. Look for

```
hw.gpu.mode = host
```